# PHP Add data in same column with multiple form input

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table with v_name and l_value column i have to add data from

```
    id       v_name    l_value
---------- ---------- ----------
1          SITE_URL    localhost/sitename

2          SITE_EMAIL  email@email.com
```

and my form is

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" >
<div class="form-group">
<label>Page Url</label>
<input type="hidden" placeholder="Enter Page Title" class="form-control"  name="v_name" id="SITE_URL" value="SITE_URL" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Page Title" class="form-control"  name="l_value" id="SITE_URL" value="" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Page Email</label>
<input type="hidden" placeholder="Enter Page Title" class="form-control" name="v_name" id="SITE_EMAIL" value="SITE_EMAIL" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Page Title" class="form-control"  name="l_value" id="SITE_EMAIL" value="" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="submit">submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

i have 2 input but i want my data to add in single table column.

Comment: where's the PHP?

Comment: And WHY the upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[]` notation in `name` attributes:

```
<label>Page Url</label>
<input type="hidden" placeholder="Enter Page Title" class="form-control"  name="v_name[]" id="SITE_URL" value="SITE_URL" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Page Title" class="form-control"  name="l_value[]" id="SITE_URL" value="" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Page Email</label>
<input type="hidden" placeholder="Enter Page Title" class="form-control" name="v_name[]" id="SITE_EMAIL" value="SITE_EMAIL" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Page Title" class="form-control"  name="l_value[]" id="SITE_EMAIL" value="" required>
</div>
```

On serverside you can access values through `$_POST` array (if request method is POST):

```
foreach ($_POST['v_name'] as $key => $name) {
    echo $name . ' and ' . $_POST['l_value'][$key];
}
```